# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Яндекс" обеспечивает сайты трафиком, как правительство обеспечивает людей социальными программами.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна. Предложение сложноподчиненное. Союз как здесь присоединяет придаточное сравнения.